# VB.NET get values from database and create dropdown menu

Tags: vb.net

I have function which should return some values:

```
Public Function vratiTvrtke(ByVal hwid As String)
    Dim hardware As String = hwid
    Dim result = New List(Of String)()
    Try
        ManageConnection(False, konekcija) 'Open connection'
        Dim strQuery As String = "SELECT tvrtke_naziv, dabase FROM info.tvrtke;"
        Dim SqlCmd As New MySqlCommand(strQuery, dbCon)
        Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read()

        End While
        reader.Close()
        Return result
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " & ex.ToString())
        Return Nothing
    Finally
        ManageConnection(True, konekcija) 'Close connection
    End Try
End Function
```

With data returned from function above i should make a menu:

```
 Public Function pripremiSucelje()

    Dim barmanager1 As New BarManager
    Dim barButtonItem = New BarButtonItem()
    barButtonItem.Content = [tvrtke_naziv]
    barButtonItem.Name = [dabase]
    Tvrtka.Items.Add(barButtonItem)
End Function
```

The thing is, in second function i should probably implement a "for each" loop because first function will return multiple rows.

How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your function to add the data to the list of this class:

```
Public Class ReturnList
    Public Property tvrtke_naziv As string
    Public Property dabase As string
End class
```

Here the function to get the result to the list:

```
Public Sub vratiTvrtke(ByVal hwid As String)
    Dim hardware As String = hwid
    Dim result = New List(Of ReturnList)
    Try
        ManageConnection(False, konekcija) 'Open connection'
        Dim strQuery As String = "SELECT tvrtke_naziv, dabase FROM info.tvrtke;"
        Dim SqlCmd As New MySqlCommand(strQuery, dbCon)
        Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read()
            Dim TempResult As New ReturnList
            TempResult.tvrtke_naziv = reader(0)
            TempResult.dabase =  reader(1)
            result.Add (TempResult)
        End While
        reader.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " & ex.ToString())
    Finally
        ManageConnection(True, konekcija) 'Close connection
    End Try
    pripremiSucelje(result)
End Function
```

then just add a `For Each` Loop:

```
Public Function pripremiSucelje(ByVal MyList As List(Of ReturnList)
    For Each item As ReturnList in MyList
        Dim barmanager1 As New BarManager
        Dim barButtonItem = New BarButtonItem()
        barButtonItem.Content = item.tvrtke_naziv
        barButtonItem.Name = item.dabase
        Tvrtka.Items.Add(barButtonItem)
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: @RaceLt No problem just remember as soon your working with databases is quite practical and good practice to create classes that fit and help handle your data.